# Keypad 4x4 in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, keypress, keypad

Can anyone explain to me what is the meaning of this code :

```
byte rowPins[numRows] = {9, 8, 7, 6}; //Rows 0 to 3
byte colPins[numCols]= {5, 4, 3, 2}; //Columns 0 to 3
```

How do they get the number of `{9, 8, 7, 6}` and `{5, 4, 3, 2}`. Here is the full code:

```
/*4x4 Matrix Keypad connected to Arduino
This code prints the key pressed on the keypad to the serial port*/
#include <Keypad.h>
const byte numRows= 4; //number of rows on the keypad
const byte numCols= 4; //number of columns on the keypad

//keymap defines the key pressed according to the row and columns just as appears on the keypad
char keymap[numRows][numCols]= {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

//Code that shows the the keypad connections to the arduino terminals
byte rowPins[numRows] = {9, 8, 7, 6}; //Rows 0 to 3
byte colPins[numCols]= {5, 4, 3, 2}; //Columns 0 to 3

//initializes an instance of the Keypad class
Keypad myKeypad= Keypad(makeKeymap(keymap), rowPins, colPins, numRows, numCols);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
//If key is pressed, this key is stored in 'keypressed' variable
//If key is not equal to 'NO_KEY', then this key is printed out
//if count=17, then count is reset back to 0 (this means no key is pressed during the whole keypad scan process

void loop() {
  char keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();
  if (keypressed != NO_KEY) {
    Serial.print(keypressed);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is unclear about the comment above that piece of code?

Comment: @AnthonyLauly If my post was helpful and you think it should help someone in future accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the code seems easy to understand. Along with the comment it is clear as a crystal. But as you said, you need an explanation, I will provide an answer :

```
const byte numRows= 4; //number of rows on the keypad
const byte numCols= 4; //number of columns on the keypad
```

In the above given piece of code, two byte vaiables would be declared named `numRows` and `numCols` and initialized each with the value 4.

```
byte rowPins[numRows] = {9, 8, 7, 6}; //Rows 0 to 3
byte colPins[numCols]= {5, 4, 3, 2}; //Columns 0 to 3
```

So here is the code that you are stuck at. Two byte array would be declared named `rowPins` and `colPins` each of size 4 (since value of `numRows` and `numCols` are 4). Which would range from 0 to 3 (like array in c or java). In this numbers 9,8,7,6 would be assigned to array `rowPins` and 5,4,3,2 will be assigned to array `colPins`. Now how or where will these values be. They will be stored in a sequential way from index 0 to index 3. i.e

```
rowPins[0]=9
rowPins[1]=8
rowPins[2]=7
rowPins[3]=6
colPins[0]=5
colPins[1]=4
colPins[2]=3
colPins[3]=2
```

This is how they get those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

They are not getting the numbers they are assigning it to the arduino pins 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

```
byte rowPins[numRows] = {9, 8, 7, 6}; //Rows 0 to 3
byte colPins[numCols]= {5, 4, 3, 2}; //Columns 0 to 3
```

you can also use 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 pins too. Just check what pins you are assigning for the row and column inputs and then write the code according to it.